# Uniqueness of Limit of a function

Tags: analysis

I have read that limit of a function at a point, say c,if it  exist,is unique.What if c is an isolated point.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the concept of limit of a function at a point is defined only for non-isolated points. Otherwise, a function may well have several limits at the same point.